# Getting error while creating two object from one object using loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript as I am trying to do something in that I am creating two object from one object.

my Parent object is

```
payload = { docType: 'ProduceRateAsset',
  PRODUCE: 'Banana',
  STATE: 'MH',
  COUNTRY: 'IN',
  BASE_UNIT: 'KG',
  SELECTED_UNIT: { NAME: 'LB', WEIGHT: 40 },
  RATES:
   [ { VARIETY: 'ABC',
       MinRate: { UNIT: 'LB', CURRENCY: 'INR', VALUE: 0.49 },
       MarketRate: { UNIT: 'LB', CURRENCY: 'INR', VALUE: 0.53 } },
     { VARIETY: 'XYZ',
       MinRate: { UNIT: 'LB', CURRENCY: 'INR', VALUE: 0.31 },
       MarketRate: { UNIT: 'LB', CURRENCY: 'INR', VALUE: 0.33 } } ] }
```

from that I am trying two object like below

```
   A =  { 
     PRODUCE: 'Banana',
    STATE: 'MH',
    COUNTRY: 'IN',
    BASE_UNIT: 'KG',
    VARIETY: 'ABC',
    MinRate: 0.49,
    MarketRate: 0.53,
    timeStamp: 2021-01-09T15:45:20.000Z };

   B =  { 
     PRODUCE: 'Banana',
    STATE: 'MH',
    COUNTRY: 'IN',
    BASE_UNIT: 'KG',
    VARIETY: 'XYZ',
    MinRate: 0.31,
    MarketRate: 0.33,
    timeStamp: 2021-01-09T15:45:20.000Z }
```

I tried below code which give me error as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'VARIETY' of undefined`

```
 var Data = {}
    var mylist = []
   let currentDate = new Date();
    for (let i = 0; i <3; i++) {
    
        Data.PRODUCE = payload.PRODUCE
        Data.STATE = payload.STATE
        Data.COUNTRY = payload.COUNTRY
        Data.BASE_UNIT = payload.BASE_UNIT
      
        Data.VARIETY = payload.RATES[i].VARIETY
        Data.MinRate = payload.RATES[i].MinRate.VALUE
        Data.MarketRate = payload.RATES[i].MarketRate.VALUE;
        Data.timeStamp = new Date(currentDate.toLocaleString());
        mylist.push(GRNData);

      };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because `payload.RATE` has two elements.

But you are trying to get third elements.

```js
payload = {
  docType: 'ProduceRateAsset',
  PRODUCE: 'Banana',
  STATE: 'MH',
  COUNTRY: 'IN',
  BASE_UNIT: 'KG',
  SELECTED_UNIT: { NAME: 'LB', WEIGHT: 40 },
  RATES: [
    {
      VARIETY: 'ABC',
      MinRate: { UNIT: 'LB', CURRENCY: 'INR', VALUE: 0.49 },
      MarketRate: { UNIT: 'LB', CURRENCY: 'INR', VALUE: 0.53 },
    },
    {
      VARIETY: 'XYZ',
      MinRate: { UNIT: 'LB', CURRENCY: 'INR', VALUE: 0.31 },
      MarketRate: { UNIT: 'LB', CURRENCY: 'INR', VALUE: 0.33 },
    },
  ],
};

let currentDate = new Date();

const res = payload.RATES.map((rate) => ({
  PRODUCE: payload.PRODUCE,
  STATE: payload.STATE,
  COUNTRY: payload.COUNTRY,
  BASE_UNIT: payload.BASE_UNIT,

  VARIETY: rate.VARIETY,
  MinRate: rate.MinRate.VALUE,
  MarketRate: rate.MarketRate.VALUE,
  timeStamp: new Date(currentDate.toLocaleString()),
}));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data you're using is the data you provided, the answer is simple: you only have 2 rates, but you're trying to perform this operation on 3 rates. You loop condition means that the loop will be executed 3 times, looking for 3 rates. You can fix this (and make it more modular) by changing your loop condition to

```js
for (let i = 0; i < payload.RATES.length; i++) {...}
```